# Buffer is null when uploading to SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint

This is my problem:

**Scenario:**

I have a word document. I edit it via code and then i try to upload it to a Sharepoint Document Library.

**The Code:**

```
using (MemoryStream msWord = new MemoryStream())
            {
                msWord.Write(wordTemplateBinary, 0, wordTemplateBinary.Length);

                using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(msWord, true))
                {
                     //do something
                }
                string docFileName, docUploadUrl;
                SPFile fileDOC;

                docFileName = Path.ChangeExtension("File", "pdf");
                pdfUploadUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", site.RootWeb.Site.Url, "GeneratedDOCs", docFileName);
                fileDOC = site.RootWeb.Files.Add(docUploadUrl, msWord, true);
            }
```

**The Problem:**

The last line `fileDOC = site.RootWeb.Files.Add(docUploadUrl, docFile, true);` throws an exception - the buffer is null.

**What I tried:**

I actually saved the document on my local machine. When I opened it it looked exactly the way I wanted. There is nothing wrong with the document as far as I know. How come this buffer is null and the file is ok.

Comment: I do not see that your byte array docFile which you provide to Add method is initialized anywhere.

Comment: Sorry about that. What you see up there is only part of the code. Otherways I checked - the problem is not there

Comment: Are you sure? Because in your code example i can see that you edit some word document but this document does not take any part in upload to sharepoint staff.

Comment: Check this out, looks like the same: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50106/appending-text-to-an-spfile-in-document-library-creating-file-if-necessary/50199#50199

Comment: I just updated the code. The previous code was an older version in which I did some things with the docFile. I tought that there might be a problem there but I still get the same result

Comment: Have you tried to put Add method call inside using statement? I mean for WordprocessingDocument object. Maybe dispose closed the stream is disposed and that is why you cannot get data.

Comment: Well no according to MSDN you must dispose the WordProcessingDocument before uploading or saving the file, or you will get problems with the output file, but I will try that - I'm totaly out of options